# media player crash after back button is pressed and open app again

Tags: java, android, media-player

Well my app have a menu when it starts, there you hit a button to begin with the app. As soon as it starts a mediaplayer start playing, but if I click back button, hit the button to start app again and then click button to stop music the app crashes. heres the code for that. It crashed at a cellphone but in emulator it works fine. Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks

```
int cancion = 1, cancion1 = 1;
MediaPlayer song, song1, song2, song3, song4;
if (cancion == 1)
    {
        song1.start();
        playing = true;
        song1.setLooping(true);
        song = song1;
    }
music.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            song.pause();
            song.seekTo(0);
            playing = false;
            cancion = cancion+1;

            if (cancion == 5)
            {
                cancion = 1;
            }
            if (cancion == 1)
            {
                song1.start();
                playing = true;
                song1.setLooping(true);
                song = song1;
            }
            else if (cancion == 2)
            {
                song2.start();
                playing = true;
                song2.setLooping(true);
                song = song2;
            }
            else if (cancion == 3)
            {
                song3.start();
                playing = true;
                song3.setLooping(true);
                song = song3;
            }
            else if (cancion == 4)
            {
                song4.start();
                playing = true;
                song4.setLooping(true);
                song = song4;
            }

        return true;
    }
});
    music.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!playing)
            {
                song.start();
                playing = true;
            }

            else
            {
                song.pause();
                song.seekTo(0);
                playing = false;
                cancion1 = 2;
            }
        }
});
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!song.isPlaying() && cancion1 != 2)
    {
        song.start();
        playing = true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(song.isPlaying())
    {
        song.pause();
        song.seekTo(0);
        playing = false;
    }
}
```

LogCat:

04-22 22:12:47.151: W/ActivityNative(12915): send ACTIVITY_IDLE_TRANSACTION
04-22 22:12:47.541: W/dalvikvm(12915): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at com.try.player.DragActivity$5.onClick(DragActivity.java:1772)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-22 22:12:47.551: E/AndroidRuntime(12915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onPause()` to release all the `MediaPlayer` Objects instead of trying to restart song currently playing.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    song.release();
    song1.release();
    //and so on

}
```

Comment: No it doesn't work either. Actualy it doesn't get the error allways.

Comment: Your error is on this line because something is null: E/AndroidRuntime(12915): at com.try.player.DragActivity$5.onClick(DragActivity.java:1772) 04-22

Comment: I will give it a try eliminating that line. Thanks

Comment: Thanks found the error. I have to release all my media players. Including the one at line 1772